# How to break out of python comprehensive list after printing the output once

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here is my code to print the reverse of DNA sequence, only if the string

```
contain character ["A","T","G","C"]

dna=input("Enter DNA sequnce")
[print(dna[::-1]) for x in dna if x in["A","T","G","C"]]

input: ATGC

the output:
CGTA
CGTA
CGTA
CGTA
```

How do I prevent the code from looping the number of characters present in the string. Can I get the output once and break the loop?

Comment: What is you rexpected output for a sequence that contains other chars?

Comment: You want to print, if it matches any character or all characters i.e A T G C

Comment: Do not use print in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying something functional programming tricks? Here I recommend the PyFunctional lib to do DNA stuff, cause PyFunctional seems to be born with handling sequence problems, hoping you can benefit from it.

to install functional

```
pip install PyFunctional
```

For your case, the code looks like:

```
from functional import seq
from operator import add

data = 'ATGC'

result = (seq(list(data))
          .filter(lambda x: x in {"A", "T", "G", "C"})
          .reduce(add))[::-1]

# CGTA
print(result)
```

From above, we can see we avoid the for-loop, and use functional programming teches like filter, but we go further by combining the method into a pipline chain, to avoid nested functional methods(something like map(list(filter())) )

BTW: using x in["A","T","G","C"] is quite slow, instead you should use x in {"A","T","G","C"} which can take advantage of the hash set.

For more info, check PyFunctional on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFunctional), or the [Github](https://github.com/EntilZha/PyFunctional)

Answer (score 2):

basically your code is checking one character at time , and if it is matched its printing the whole list in reverse ,try using

```
dna=input("Enter DNA sequnce")
result=[ x for x in dna if x in["A","T","G","C"]]
print "".join(result[::-1])
```

if you don't want to use list comprehensions then you can use this as well

```
for i in allowed_char:
    if i in dna:
        print dna[::-1]
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try sth along the lines of:

```
dna = input("Enter DNA sequnce") 
print(''.join(x for x in dna[::-1] if x in "ATGC"))
# CTGA -> AGTC
# ABCD -> CA
```